# Including a Predictor in a Pipeline with Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn-pipeline

Actually this doubt is more like -- "why is this code working properly?".

I was working out a problem from a text book. Specifically, the problem was to build a Pipeline that had a Data Preparation phase (remove NA values, perform Feature Scaling etc.) and then a Prediction phase, which involves a Predictor trained on the transformed dataset and returning its predictions.

Here, we used a Support Vector Regressor module (sklearn.svm.svr).

I tried some code of mine, but it didn't work. So I looked up the actual solution provided by the author of the textbook -

```
prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preparation', data_prep),
    ('svm_reg', SVR(kernel='rbf',C=30000,gamma='scale'))
])

prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline.fit(x_train,y_train)

some_data = x_train.iloc[:4]
print("Predictions for a subset of Training Set:",prepare_select_and_predict_pipeline.predict(some_data))
```

I tried this code, and it does work as expected.
How can it work properly? My main objections are:

1. We have only **fit** the dataset, but where are we actually
   **transforming** it? We are not calling a transform() function anywhere...
2. Also, how can we use the predict() function with this pipeline? SVR
   might be a part of this pipeline, but so are the other transformers,
   and they don't have a predict() function.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform `fit` on the `Pipeline` scikit-learn performs under the hood `fit_transform` of preprocessing step and `fit` on last step (classifier|regressor). When you call `predict` on the `Pipeline` scikit-learn perform `transform` on the preprocessing stage and `predict` on the last step.

Now, the definition of the model is not the last step but all the steps that takes in data and output results. The Pipeline is now a model. If you used GridSearchCV which has Pipelines, and Pipelines has preprocessing and final steps (regressor|classifier), then GridSearchCV is now the model.

See [Pipeline Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html?highlight=pipeline#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline)